# how can strcpy function accept both adress as well as string constant?

Tags: c, function, pointers, strcpy

```
void main() 
{
    char str1[10], str2[10] = "haha";
    strcpy(str1, str2);
    puts(str1);
    strcpy(str1, "tictoc");
    puts(str1) ;
}
```

how can adress as well as string constant passed to a pointer variable through pre-defined strcpy function in c language as shown in above code?

Comment: str1 and str are not constants. The str variable has a value, but it is not a `const`. The parameters passed to strcpy() are both the address of the variable.

Comment: str2 is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed to a function, it decays into a pointer to the first element.

In the case of the first call, both `str1` and `str` have type `char [10]`.  These each decay to a `char *` when passed to `strcpy`.  Similarly, the string constant `"tictoc"` has type `char [7]` (one byte for each character in the string plus the terminating null byte) which also decays to `char *`.

A function that expects a `const` parameter can take a non-const version of the same datatype.  The second parameter to `strcpy` expects a `const char *`, so a `char *` will also satisfy this argument.

If on the other hand you try to pass a const variable to a function expecting a non-const type, that will generate a compiler warning.

Comment: thanks, can u please  explain how does const perform its job,,,,?

Comment: @SuvashRaj having the `const` as part of the function parameter, as in `const char*` guarantees that the function won't modify the data you pass in.  This is useful to know how much you can trust the function to edit the data you give it.  This may be desired, maybe not, depending on the function and what you need to do.  But passing your mutable `char*` into a function asking for `const char*` just means that it won't be changed while being processed in that function. In this case, it is just being used to copy from the `const` one to the non-const one.